# display text in jtextfield takes too long

Tags: java, netbeans, jtextfield, filechooser

I would really appreciate your help;
I'm using java (netbeans ide), i'm working with filechooser, when i choose a directory, i need to display it's path on a jtextfield. However nothing appears until the program is over (untill all the files of the directory are parsed and treated), I would like it to appear as soon as the program starts.
Please help me out, here is my code:

```
    JFileChooser fch = new JFileChooser("C:\\");
    fch.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);

    fch.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    int ret = fch.showOpenDialog(null); 
    int apr=0;
    if (ret==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        apr=1;
        jTextField1.setText(fch.getSelectedFile().toString());
    }
    else jTextField1.setText("Nothing clicked!!!");
.......... the rest of the code .........
```

when I don't click the msg appears, yet when i do, the path won't apprear till after the program is finished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code of `JFileChooser...` probably resides in an ActionListener. This is handled on the sole event handling thread. So do an `invokeLater`.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    ...

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() { // Added
        ... rest of the code
    }); // Added
}
```

Here I think "rest of the code" might be causing the delay, but you might try differently.

Comment: the probelm that "....rest of the code.." uses variables that are used in previous part

Comment: If the variables used are **final** then they may be used. If not feasible you may make a new final variable, copy of the old one. _The reason for final (=variable may not be assigned to) is that in the closure (Runnable) an invisible copy of that variable is made and used, as the old variable's life time and stack location ends with function call return._

Comment: thanks a lot, your solution worked just fine. I would like to ask you another question please, I have a function that parses all the files and directories, since the operation takes a time, i want to show a progressbare, or anything similar to tell the user to be patient and that the program is still running. However even thought I increment the progress value gradually nothing appears until the function is over and and the value of the progress value is 100. Can you help me please!

Comment: That has the same cause: the work should be done on another thread, parallel to the GUI. For this one typically would use a SwingWorker; I did a search [here](http://alvinalexander.com/source-code/java/source-code-java-swingworker-progressbar-example-swingworker-background-thread)

Comment: I Tried your solution, it worked but i still have a synchronization problem, the bar sometimes ends before the function result come out and sometimes after.

Comment: Sorry I can't help there. Maybe start with a minimal example and make that work in a separate protyping app.

Comment: I will post my code, please take a look and tell me what i did wrong. `code`